# acts as votable votes are recorded twice per user for some reason

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

for some reason votes are counted twice each time a user votes. I can't identify where the error is. [See screenshot for duplicate count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xylnS.png)It seems like im firing double jquery requests but I don't know which to remove. rails-jquery gem or jquery in application.js

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="like">
      <%= link_to like_list_path(@list), :class => "like-btn", method: 
      :put, remote: :true do %>
        <%= liked_list(@list) %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to "", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#likeModalLong" do %>
        <span class="likes-count"><%= @list.get_upvotes.size %></span>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

**lists_controller.rb**

```
def vote
 if !current_user.liked? @list
   @list.liked_by current_user
   #create like notification for the user
   Notification.create(recipient: @list.user, actor: current_user, 
  action: "liked", notifiable: @list)
 elsif current_user.liked? @list
  @list.unliked_by current_user
 end
end
```

**vote.js.erb**

```
<% if current_user.liked? @list %>
 $('.fa-heart').addClass('liked');
<% else %>
 $('.fa-heart').removeClass('liked');
<% end %>
$('.likes-count').html("<%= @list.get_upvotes.size %>")
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def liked_list(list)
   if current_user.username == "guestuser"
    liked = ''
   else
    liked = current_user.liked?(list) ? 'liked' : ''
   end
  content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-heart #{liked}")
 end
end
```

UPDATE: not sure which one to remove

```
**application.js**

//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require cocoon
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require social-share-button
//= require_tree .
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'
gem 'redis'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.9'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2'
gem 'acts_as_follower', github: 'tcocca/acts_as_follower', branch: 'master'
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'link_thumbnailer'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.11.1'
```

Comment: can you post the code where `liked_list` method is defined?

Comment: Sure, sorry! I edited the original question. Basically I display the heart icon in a different color here based on whether the user has already liked it or not. I also have guest users so there the heart is always inactive = ' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the rails jquery gem and also adding the code in `application.js`?  It sounds like your Rails JS is being loaded twice and double-submitting your AJAX form.

Check your app logs for duplicate requests to confirm.

Comment: That's indeed what happened. Thanks a lot. I updvoted your answer but my votes are not displayed publicly yet since I'm new on Stackoverflow. Thanks a lot though !